# Why does my dropdown menu shift on hover?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

My website (http://www.oia.co.za/schedules/) has a horizontal navigation menu with dropdowns on hover, and the darn thing shifts the neighbouring list-item the width of the dropdown on hover.

I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem is, and my eyes are square from looking at the CSS all night.

I know it is something stupidly simple, and I've just looked at it for too long...

Comment: The reason this happens is because the inner `<ul>` forces the outer `<li>` to expand to contain it when your CSS kicks in to display it. Both suggestions below should work - just thought you could use an explanation as to why they work.

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the explanation :)

Comment: De nada. Don't forget to mark the answer that works as accepted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try updating the dropdown ul to be absolutely positioned:

```
#top_navigation ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}

#top_navigation ul {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Give `position:absolute` to your `Dropdown` UL. Write like this:

```
    .menu-item{position:relative}

.sub-menu{
 position:absolute;
 top:30px;
 left:0;
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it, although I'm not sure what that random "left;" is in there for.